# Converting List of JsonString to Class Object

Tags: c#, list, model

This is my result JSON

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "AAA",
            "Results": [
                "{\"name\":\"Maths\",\"type\":\"Person\",\"subType\":null}",
                "{\"name\":\"English\",\"type\":\"Person\",\"subType\":null}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BBB",
            "Results": [
                "{\"name\":\"Bio\",\"type\":\"Person\",\"subType\":null}",
                "{\"name\":\"Physics\",\"type\":\"Person\",\"subType\":null}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my **Value Model**

```
public class ValueModel
{
public string name { get; set; }    
public List<string> Results { get; set; }
}
```

**Main Model:**

```
public class MainModel
{
public List<ValueModel> value {get;set;}
}
```

The Result value always comes in JSON string format which I couldn't change.

Now I already have a separate class for the **Result** as below

```
public class ResultModel
{
public string name {get;set;}
public string type {get;set;}
public string subType {get;set;}
}
```

All I wanted is to convert the Results Jsonstring into ResultModel

So far I tried like in the getter setter itself but not working

```
public class ValueModel
{
public string name { get; set; }    
public List<string> Results { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<ResultModel> ProperResults
        {           
            get
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Results , Formatting.Indented);
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultModel>>(json);
            }
        }
}
```

**Update 1**
@Aleks solution worked perfectly, but the issue is I'm having another Json property like `@odata.count` in my result JSON

```
{   "@odata.count": 2
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "AAA",
            "Results": [
                "{\"name\":\"Maths\",\"type\":\"Person\",\"subType\":null}",
                "{\"name\":\"English\",\"type\":\"Person\",\"subType\":null}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BBB",
            "Results": [
                "{\"name\":\"Bio\",\"type\":\"Person\",\"subType\":null}",
                "{\"name\":\"Physics\",\"type\":\"Person\",\"subType\":null}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I tried to modify the template like

```
var template = new { odataCount=0,value = new[] {new {name = "", Results = new string[0]}}};
```

which is not working bcos it couldn't able to map the `@odata.count` element

Comment: It is unclear to me what the actual problem is. What doesn't work in your code?

Comment: I think you want to deserialize only the `Results` array from your JSON string. Hence you would need to ignore the `name` property. You can do that by: `JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
    List<ResultModel> values = jo.SelectToken("name", false).ToObject<List<ResultModel>>();
`

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was trying to convert the `results` which is a nested json string into ResultModel class

Comment: But what is the problem? What does it do and what not? @Jayendran

Comment: I couldn't able to convert the `results` into the `Resultmodel` class using the getter and setter @PatrickHofman

Comment: Shouldn't your template be: `var template = new {@odataCount=0,value = new[] {new {name = "", Results = new string[0]}}};` ?

Comment: @RahulSharma tried already not working, I think this will work only using [JsonProperty]

Comment: @Jayendran Yes I agree with you. You would need [JsonProperty] to do your mappings as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input contain nested Json so you should deserialize it in several passes

You can define your `ValueModel` like

```
public class ValueModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<ResultModel> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Now deserialize your input to temp anonymous object:

```
var input = "{\r\n    \"value\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"name\": \"AAA\",\r\n            \"Results\": [\r\n                \"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Maths\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"Person\\\",\\\"subType\\\":null}\",\r\n                \"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"English\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"Person\\\",\\\"subType\\\":null}\"\r\n            ]\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"name\": \"BBB\",\r\n            \"Results\": [\r\n                \"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Bio\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"Person\\\",\\\"subType\\\":null}\",\r\n                \"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Physics\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"Person\\\",\\\"subType\\\":null}\"\r\n            ]\r\n        }\r\n    ]\r\n}";

var template = new {value = new[] {new {name = "", Results = new string[0]}}};
var mainModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(input, template);
```

At this moment you can get expected result

```
var result = new MainModel
{
    value = mainModel.value.Select(x => new ValueModel
    {
        name = x.name,
        Results = x.Results.Select(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel>).ToList()
    }).ToList()
};
```

---

I don't know how to extract `@odata.count` in a single pass, but you can use `JObject` for this:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(input);
(int) jObject["@odata.count"]; // == 2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Upvoted, the solution is working perfectly but the thing is I'm facing other issue related to JSON mapping, Pls see my *update1* in my question. If you have any solution?